python + Thread\TrocessPoolExecutor
I am new for concurrent.futures. Is there any problem in the following script?
def read_excel(self):
    '''
    read excel -> parse df -> store into sql
    '''

    file_list = ['分诊咨询记录','客户消费明细表','电话网络情况明细表']
    tpool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    ppool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    tfutures = list()
    pfutures = list()
    write_futures = list()
    for file in file_list:
        path = os.path.join(self.config['his']['root'],file)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            tfutures.append(tpool.submit(self._read_excel,path,file)) 
    for tfuture in as_completed(tfutures):
        pfutures.append(ppool.submit(self._parse_df,tfuture.result()))
    for pfuture in as_completed(pfutures):
        result = pfuture.result()
        write_futures.append(tpool.submit(self.update_data,result[1],result[0]))
    for _ in as_completed(write_futures):pass
    tpool.shutdown()
    ppool.shutdown()

Will the for loop block the code？ I mean, when the first read_excel finishes, will the the first parse_df start working? What if read_excel pool did not finish all tasks, and the first parse_df filnished? Will the first update_data start working?
I hope the script will not be blocked. When a task finishes, the next step should immediately start.

Will the script cause problems?
Is the script meeting my goal? How to achieve my goal?


What happened when you ran this code?

failed! error information:
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
result = pfuture.result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
......
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'BufferedReader' instances

All/Any values returned from a subprocess have to pickled. Thus the issue is with either of self._parse_df() or self.update_data() returning inappropriate objects

As László Hunyadi has responded, your current code will not be submitting anything to the multiprocessing pool until all tasks submitted to self._read_excel completes. But I would solve this problem differently.
Presumably the parse_df method involves CPU-intensive processing, otherwise you would not be executing this in a multiprocessing pool. Of course, if the processing is not sufficiently intensive, the reduction in time by running these tasks in parallel will not compensate for the additional overhead incurred by using multiprocessing. In that case you would be better off to use multithreading for everything. But assuming the need to execute parse_df in a separate process, then I would organize the code more simply as follows based on the idea that you can pass a multiprocessing pool to a multithreading pool worker function. This results in simpler, more easily followed code. In the following code a new worker method worker has been created and the main thread only has to submit tasks to this worker, which does all the required processing:
class SomeClass:

    def worker(self, path, file, ppool):
        """This executes in a multithreading pool."""

        result = self._read_excel(path, file) # Simple function call
        # Run the CPU-intensive processing in the passed multiprocessing pool:
        future = ppool.submit(self._parse_df, result)
        result = future.result()
        # Finally, we continue executing
        self.update_data(result[1], result[0])

    def read_excel(self):
        '''
        read excel -> parse df -> store into sql
        '''

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as tpool, \
        ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ppool:
            for path, file in path_file_list:
                tpool.submit(self.worker, path, file, ppool)
            file_list = ['分诊咨询记录','客户消费明细表','电话网络情况明细表']
            for file in file_list:
                path = os.path.join(self.config['his']['root'], file)
                if os.path.exists(path):
                    tpool.submit(self.worker, path, file))

        # The implicit calls to shutdown will wait for all
        # submitted tasks to the multithreading pool to complete:
        ...

Since your code is not a complete, minimal reproducible example, I have provided some missing methods for demo purposes so you see how everything works in practice.
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

class ExcelProcessor:
    def worker(self, path, file, ppool):
        """This executes in a multithreading pool."""

        result = self._read_excel(path, file) # Simple function call
        # Run the CPU-intensive processing in the passed multiprocessing pool:
        future = ppool.submit(self._parse_df, result)
        result = future.result()
        # Finally, we continue executing
        self.update_data(result[1], result[0])

    def read_excel(self):
        '''
        read excel -> parse df -> store into sql
        '''

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as tpool, \
        ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ppool:
            path_file_list = [
                ('path1', 'file1'),
                ('path2', 'file2'),
                ('path3', 'file3'),
                ]
            for path, file in path_file_list:
                tpool.submit(self.worker, path, file, ppool)

        # The implicit calls to shutdown will wait for all
        # submitted tasks to the multithreading pool to complete:
        ...

    def _read_excel(self, path, file):
        return path + file   # Just concatenate the arguments

    def _parse_df(self, path_file):
        """ Return argument and the argument reversed"""
        return path_file, path_file[::-1]

    def update_data(self, s1, s2):
        """Just output the results."""
        print(s1, s2, flush=True)


# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExcelProcessor().read_excel()

Prints:
1elif1htap path1file1
2elif2htap path2file2
3elif3htap path3file3


Great! Your code is precisely what I need. All I/O-intensive tasks are in the thread pool, while all CPU-intensive tasks are in the process pool. Moreover, all tasks are executed sequentially without delay. Thank you very much

Yes, the as_completed function returns an iterator that yields futures as they complete. The 2nd and 3rd for loops will block until all the tasks submitted in the previous for loop are completed. If I understood correctly, you want the next step to start immediately after a task finishes.
You could use a single ThreadPoolExecutor and chain the task using the Future.add_done_callback method:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os
def read_excel(self):
    file_list = ['分诊咨询记录','客户消费明细表','电话网络情况明细表']
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    def on_read_done(future):
        df, file = future.result()
        parse_future = pool.submit(self._parse_df, df)
        parse_future.add_done_callback(on_parse_done)
    def on_parse_done(future):
        parsed_data, file = future.result()
        updated_future = pool.submit(self.update_data, parsed_data, file)
    for file in file_list:
        path = os.path.join(self.config['his']['root'], file)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            read_future = pool.submit(self._read_excel, path, file)
            read_future.add_done_callback(on_read_done)
    pool.shutdown()


Presumably the OP is also using a multiprocessing pool to be used for processing that is CPU intensive.
